# Login as root using Laravel Forge

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-forge

I have executed a recipe on a server at Laravel Forge. The recipe is for some reason run as *root*. When connecting to the server through ssh, I use user *forge*. But since the recipe was run as *root*, I cannot access some processes. My first thought was to log in as *root*, but I think Forge has disabled that. Using `ssh root@ip` results in `Permission denied (publickey).`

How do I login as root using Forge?

**Edit:**
Apparently, on Forge, you can chose the user on which the recipe is run.

Comment: Log in as `forge`, then use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up first adding `forge ALL = NOPASSWD : ALL` via *sudo visudo* and then adding an alias for `ssh -t forge@ip "sudo -i"`.